# aws quicksight dashboard embed url expiring after 5 minutes even after embeding in whitelist domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

when I try to embed dashboard URL to my website, it is becoming invalid after 5 minutes even I set `--session-lifetime-in-minutes` to max value ie 600. is this behavior normal? how to increase validity dashboard embed URL session up to 10 hrs as they said in docs

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/get-dashboard-embed-url.html?highlight=quicksight